# What is the precedence of the meta-operator ...?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-precedence, ellipsis, variadic-templates

What is the precedence of the meta-operator `...` whose job is to unpack template type parameter packs? I imagine it's pretty low, but how low is it? The C++ standard says:

> The precedence of operators is not directly specified, but it can be derived from the syntax.

Anyone up for the challenge? Of course, `...` does not appear in C++03 operator precedence tables.

---

Okay, if `...` is not an operator, what exactly determines that `std::forward<Args>(args)...` applies to the the entire sequence `std::forward<Args>(args)` and not just `(args)`, for example?

Comment: what exactly is the question? it's not an operator, doesn't interact with operators. maybe you should provide an example.

Comment: @FredOverflow: some C++0x things you ask I know or can intuit, others (and this one) not. But please keep asking. I'm learning C++0x from your questions! Like, lazy bird, flies in the wake of another. :-)

Comment: @Alf: As long as everyone takes their turns at the front of the peleton then it's the best kind of lazy.

Comment: @Steve: If we're taking turns, then we would also have to cycle _answering_, otherwise it wouldn't really be taking turns. (This is a Q&A site, after all.) However, just as with answering, I'd like to keep the task of asking to those who do it best. And Fred has proven to come up with pretty darn good questions. Why disturb this equilibrium as long as we all benefit? `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Are you implying my answers suck? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an operator. From N3092 (sorry I don't have a more recent draft handy)

> [14.5.3] 4/ A pack expansion is a sequence of tokens that names one or
>   more parameter packs, followed by an ellipsis. The sequence of tokens
>   is called the pattern of the expansion; its syntax depends on the
>   context in which the expansion occurs. Pack expansions can occur in
>   the following contexts:
>
> - In an initializer-list (8.5); the pattern is an
>     initializer-clause.
> - In a base-specifier-list (10); the pattern is a base-specifier.
> - In a mem-initializer-list (12.6.2); the pattern is a
>     mem-initializer.
> - In a template-argument-list (14.3); the pattern is a
>     template-argument.
> - In a dynamic-exception-specification (15.4); the pattern is a
>     type-id.
> - In an attribute-list (7.6.1); the pattern is an attribute.
> - In a capture-list (5.1.2); the pattern is a capture. *[Example:*
>
>   ```
>   template<class ... Types> void f(Types ... rest);
>   template<class ... Types> void g(Types ... rest) {
>       f(&rest ...); // “&rest ...” is a pack expansion; “&rest” is its pattern
>   }
>   ```
>
>   *— end example]*

Comment: This is an excellent answer that unfortunately is not terribly illuminating. :-)

Comment: What would make it more illuminating is examples of each case and specific cases showing how the positioning of the `...` affects which case the compiler thinks you mean.

Comment: @Omnifarious: the standard text scatters the different usages of `...` throughout the text. The relevant sections contain examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to the handy [Hyperlinked C++ BNF Grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/), a function call looks like this:

> postfix-expression ( expression-list<sub>opt</sub> )

*expression-list* is just an [*initializer-list*](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#initializer-list), which looks like this:

> initializer-clause ...<sub>opt</sub>
>     initializer-list , initializer-clause ...<sub>opt</sub>

where the ellipses are the pack expansion notation.

*initializer-clause*, in turn, can be either [*assignment-expression*](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#assignment-expression) or [*braced-init-list*](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#braced-init-list).

All this is to say, then, that the ellipsis has a lower grammatical precedence than any actual operator, so for instance the following are equivalent:

```
foo(args ^= 0x1234...) and foo((args ^= 0x1234)...)

foo(x ? args : 42...) and foo((x ? args : 42)...)
```